# why Input attribute in angular is not taking the value that I sent by the html file?

Tags: angular, input, data-binding

Hello everyone I have this problem related to Angular.

inside my  skills.component.ts .

`@Input() testfield ="";`

inside skills.component.html

```
     style="padding: 0 10%"
     class="row align-items-center">
  <p id="skill"
     class="col-2"
     style="font-family: Mulish-Bold, serif; font-size: 1.2rem; text-align: end;"
  >
    {{testfield}}
  </p>
  <p class="col-7" id="bar">

    <ngb-progressbar
      type="success"
      [value]="50">
    </ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
</div>
```

and inside the component that uses this **app-skill-bar** .

```
  <app-section-title color="#84142D" icon="bi bi-star-fill" title="Skills"></app-section-title>
  <app-skill-bar testfield="Android"></app-skill-bar>
</div>
```

the problem is that angular can't take "Android" as value for testfield. also, it doesn't desplay Android.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code or share a link of stackblitz that can reproduce the same issue?

Comment: okay this is the github link https://github.com/muath-nassar/cv-angular.git

Comment: Interesting issue ngOnChanges showing that value updated but input variable not displaying the value in html. Looking into it!

Comment: yes  this is the key point. thnx for your time.

Comment: @SparrowVic has given the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your project. The input works correctly. The problem is that you create in app.module.ts two independent components trees.
The first time a component is loaded, the value "Android" exists, but then the component is quickly reloaded with no value passed. You can analyze this by putting the debugger in ngOnInit method in your SkillBarComponent. All in all, you should remove SkillBarComponent from the bootstrap array.
[image]

Since you added SkillBarComponent in bootstrap array, it will be considered as root component and You are passing an input in the root component, which will not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right,  , You are very intelligent.